# Change bit of hex number with leading zeros in C++,(C)

Tags: c++, c, binary, hex

I have this number in hex string:

```
002A05.
```

I need to set 7-th bit of this number to 1, so after conversion I will get

```
022A05
```

But it has to work with every 6 chars hex number.

I tried converting hex string to integer via strtol, but that function strip leading zeros.

Please help me how can I solve it.

Comment: Why is stripping leading zeros a problem?

Comment: Just pad the string with leading zeroes when you convert it back to a string.

Comment: Why are strings involved in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a 24-bit number bit #7 (counting from the left, as you did in your example, not from the right, as is done conventionally) is always going to be in the second byte from the left. You can solve your problem without converting the entire number to integer by taking that second hex digit, converting it to a number 0..15, setting its bit #3 (again counting from the left), and converting the result back to a hex digit.

```
int fromHex(char c) {
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c-'0';
    } else {
        return c-'A'+10;
    }
}
char toHexDigit(int n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0'+n : 'A'+n-10;
}

char myNum[] = "002A05";
myNum[1] = toHexDigit(fromHex(myNum[1]) | 2);
printf("%s\n", myNum);
```

This prints '022A05' ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/91hkDX)).

Comment: What? I don't even see what you are saying here. In cases like this, code speaks a thousand words. If you want to 'explain' rather than 'provide magic solutions', at least make the explanation human friendly?

Comment: @sehe "I don't even see what you are saying here." Quite frankly, I find this very surprising: my answer was rather straightforward even before adding the code, explaining the last two lines of code with four lines of plain English.

Comment: "straight english" doesn't usually work. It used rather fuzzy terms (when it was _obvious_ the OP doesn't have a grasp of binary integer representations at all). It was several sentences of dense prose without attempt at structuring and it may not even be in the OP's native language. +1 for adding code, though

Answer (score 3):

```
int hex=0x002A05;
int mask = 0x020000;
printf ("%06X",hex | mask);
```

hope this helps

Comment: I corrected the format string to match the OP's request (uppercase and 6 positions with leading zeroes)

Comment: As OP wrote “set” not “switch”, I'd use OR not XOR, i.e. `|` not `^`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a string, not a hex constant, that you want to manipulate. You can do it pretty easily by bit twiddling the ascii value of the hex character. If you have char representing a hex character like `char h = '6';`, `char h = 'C';`, or `char h = '';`, you can set the 3rd from the left (2nd from the right) bit in the number that the character represents using:

```
 h = h > '7' ? h <= '9' ? h + 9 : ((h + 1) | 2) - 1 : h | 2;
```

So you can do this to the second character (4 + 3 bits) in your string. This works for any hex string with 2 or more characters. Here is your example:

```
char hex_string[] = "002A05";

// Get the second character from the string
char h = hex_string[1];

// Calculate the new character
h = h > '7' ? h <= '9' ? h + 9 : ((h + 1) | 2) - 1 : h | 2;

// Set the second character in the string to the result
hex_string[1] = h;

printf("%s", hex_string); // 022A05
```

Comment: Did you try this with `"092A05"` or `"082A05"`?

Comment: +1 That's better. The key line where you calculate the new `h` uses three different tricks to set the 2-nd bit :)

Answer (score 0):

You asked about `strtol` specifically, so to answer your question, just add padding after you convert the number with `strtol`:

```
const char *s = "002A05";
int x = strtol(s, NULL, 16);
x |= (1<<17);
printf("%.6X\n",x);
```

Comment: @Griwes works either way, but it should be `const` of course, thanks :)