# Invert 7th bit of hex string C++

Tags: c++, c, binary, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change bit of hex number with leading zeros in C++,(C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430050/change-bit-of-hex-number-with-leading-zeros-in-c-c)

I have this number in hex string:

```
002A05(7th bit is set to 0)
```

I need to invert 7-th bit of this number, so after conversion I will get

```
022A05
```

But in case

```
ABCDEF(7th bit is set to 1)
```

I need to get

```
A9CDEF
```

But it has to work with every 6 chars hex number.

It need to be 7th bit from left. I'm trying convert OUI to modified EUI64

I tried converting hex string to integer via strtol, but that function strip leading zeros.

Please help me how can I solve it.

Comment: This is almost identical to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430050/change-bit-of-hex-number-with-leading-zeros-in-c-c) you asked a couple of days ago.  Can you have a go yourself, based on the previous advice, and post code when you run into problems?

Comment: You really do have to put the effort into asking a specific question. Also, is this a C++ question or a C question? And what do you mean by you "have this number"? In what form do you have it?

Comment: The `strtol` function is in C89. It predates C++.

Comment: By the way, that's not the seventh bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void flipme(char *buf, const char *inBuf)
{
    int x;
    sscanf(inBuf, "%x", &x);
    x ^= 1 << 17;
    sprintf(buf, "%06X", x);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[16];

    flipme(buf, "002A05");
    printf("002A05->%s\n", buf);

    flipme(buf, "ABCDEF");
    printf("ABCDEF->%s\n", buf);
}
```

Output:

> 002A05->022A05
>   ABCDEF->A9CDEF

You wrote:

> I tried converting hex string to integer via strtol, but that function strip leading zeros.

The `strtol` function converts it to a *number*. It doesn't mean anything to say it strips leading zeroes because numbers don't have leading zeroes -- "6" and "06" are two different ways of writing the same number. If you want leading zeroes when you print it, you can add them then.

Comment: that i tried to do, but I can't convert it because of possible leading zeros

Comment: Then start with the right-most six characters work to the left. Alternatively, keep adding leading zeroes until the string length is a multiple of six.

Comment: It is entirely unnecessary to split anything. OP only needs to modify the 2nd char.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: If it's just a single string, he just needs to read it into an integer, flip the bit, and then write it back out in hex. It doesn't get much easier than that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I know I'm being unreasonably picky, but surely you must agree that to flip a bit of a hex number string, you only need one char of it. The rest of it is irrelevant. I think it's important to point this out, in case OP ever needs to do the same for 100 hex digits.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: That gets tricky if the string is just "0". I think the OP is having enough trouble doing things the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way, but not necessarily the cleanest;

Since only one char is affected, you can just do it using a simple string manipulation; assuming your input is in uppercase in the string `input`;

```
input[1] = "23016745AB*******89EFCD"[input[1]-48];
```

Comment: What if the input is only one character, say "4"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The requirement was "it has to work with every 6 chars hex number." but, yes, it'd obviously break with one character.

Comment: The OP was confused about that. He doesn't understand the numbers don't consist of characters, nor is there such a thing as a hex number. Hex is a way to express numbers which, once expressed in a particular base, consist of digits. Roughly, he meant a number that is capable of being expressed in six hexadecimal digits. The number 4 can be expressed in six hexadecimal digits -- 000004. (I misread the OP too until he responded to my answer a few times.)

Answer (score 0):

```
num ^ 0x020000
```

`^` is the bitwise xor operator.

Answer (score 0):

Given an integer `x`, the number with 3rd bit inverted is `x ^ 2`.
The rest of the answer was given to you [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13430153/971193).

<sub>Note: in the question the bits are counted from highest to lowest, starting at 1. Then 7th bit of a 6 digit hex number is the 3rd bit of its 2nd highest character. Normally bits are counted from lowest to highest, starting from 0 though.</sub>